# Android : Copy folder from assets to /data/data on rooted devices

Tags: android, root

Is it possible to load a folder into /data/data from android assets anyway? Actually! the folder contains data of another 3rd party app.

Please be gentle, thnx

Comment: sorry you can not access other's app data/data folder

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I think his question is bit different, seems he is already have folder with data of other app.

Comment: @Rashed Lone As mayani said you already have a 3rd party folder in your application assets and you want to write that folder to your application's data/data/ folder?

Comment: yeah! i already have the data, now i want to write that folder with 3rd party application package name to data/data, in short, i want to programatically restore another apps data thst is stored in my assets.

Comment: Likely you should use yoru main application process (ie, your Java code) to extract the data somewhere under your own private directory, and then an executable started with your `su` hack (or whatever makes your device rooted) to move or copy it to the destination directory.